# 呢 meaning "where", is it possible?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

Is it true that 呢 can mean "WHERE"??? If so, then what is the difference between 呢 and 哪儿???
I've seen those sentences and they made me wonder:

"我的杯子在哪儿? - where is my cup?" and "我的杯子呢? - where is my cup?"

The dictionary said that 呢 means "particle indicating that a previously asked question is to be applied to the preceding word ("What about ...?", "And ...?"); particle for inquiring about location ("Where is ...?"); particle signaling a pause, to emphasize the preceding words and allow the listener time to take them on board ("ok?", "are you with me?"); (at the end of a declarative sentence) particle indicating continuation of a state or action; particle indicating strong affirmation".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so as a native speaker.

呢 is only a modal particle while it is pronounced as "ne" in Pinyin.

You can use it for:

1. Interrogative mood. Use it at the end of a sentence. Sometimes you can use it for probing somebody.

For example:

> 你在做什么呢？ What are you doing?

You can remove 呢; then you are not probing.

Another usage:

> 我的杯子呢？ Where is my cup?

In my view, this is an elliptical sentence. It should be 我的杯子在哪呢？. And 在哪 means WHERE.

哪 is also has interrogative mood. So you can remove 呢 if there is 哪. (or keep it is also ok)

You must keep 呢 if you use the elliptical sentence. Because there is no interrogative mood in the rest of the sentence.

2. Emphatic mood. Use it at the end of a sentence.

> 我在跟你说话呢！ I am talking to you!

3. Something or action is happening. Use it at the end of a sentence.

> 我在学习呢。 I am studying right now.

4. Indicating a pause.

> 现在呢，已经完全不一样了。 Nowadays, well it's totally changed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's exactly right.

> 我的杯子呢？

Translates to "Where's my cup?"

---

A common one you will hear is:

> 人呢？

Which equates to something like, "Where'd you go?" -or- "Where'd he go?" -or- "Where are you?"

Comment: This can not explain "你在做什么呢？" In my view, 我的杯子呢？ is an elliptical sentence. It should be 我的杯子在哪呢？ And 呢 is the only element to make 我的杯子呢？ as a question.